# Strange behaviour with encodings

Tags: r, encoding, rstudio

I have the following code:

```
bdata[r,"COL1"][which(bdata[r,"COL1"] %in% c("eos"))] <- 2
bdata[r,"COL1"][which(bdata[r,"COL1"] %in% c("Silloin tällöin"))] <- 1
```

Where bdata is a data frame where some entries have integer values and other entries have string values such as "Silloin tällöin" or "eos". I want to replace those values by 1 and 2 respectively. When the code runs in RStudio the replacement only occurs for the "eos" case but not for the "Silloin tällöin" case. I think the problem is with the encodings due to the Scandic letters.

However, if I put a breakpoint by inserting `browser()`statements and cut and paste the lines and run them in the immediate window, the replacement occurs in both cases.

Any clues on what is going on?

Thanks in advance!

PS: here is how the vector bdata[r, "COL1"] looks like:

```
c("0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "1", "0", "1", "0", "1", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "1", "0", "1", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "1", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "1", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "1", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "1", "0", "0", "0", "", "0", "1", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "1", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "1", "0", "0", "", "0", "1", "0", "0", 
"1", "1", "0", "0", "0", "0", "1", "0", "0", "0", "1", "0", "0", 
"0", "1", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "Silloin tällöin", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "Silloin tällöin", "0", "0", "0", "Silloin tällöin", 
"Silloin tällöin", "0", "", "0", "Silloin tällöin", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "Silloin tällöin", "0", "0", "Silloin tällöin", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "Silloin tällöin", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "Silloin tällöin", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "Silloin tällöin", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "Silloin tällöin", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "Silloin tällöin", "Silloin tällöin", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"Silloin tällöin", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "Silloin tällöin", 
"0", "0", "0", "Silloin tällöin", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "Silloin tällöin", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "Silloin tällöin", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "Silloin tällöin", "0", "0", "Lähes joka päivä", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "Silloin tällöin", "0", "0", "0")
```

Comment: Can you please show the data (i.e. `bdata`)?

Comment: Hi Abdou, I've edited the post to show how the content looks like.

Comment: it's not clear what `bcos_data` is supposed to be. Is `bcos_data[r,"COL1"]` the same as `bdata[r,"COL1"]`?

Comment: Yes, thanks. I was just trying to simplify the original expression. I've edited again the post to correct that.

Comment: I've found what the problem is. Indeed, I was sourcing the code from another script. The problem was that I have to use the parameter "encoding = utf-8" for the `source()` function. Thanks for your time anyway.

Comment: Use the function `Encoding(bdata[bdata[r,"COL1"] %in% c("Silloin tällöin")])` to check what the encoding of the rows containing the string `"Silloin tällöin"` is. If you get that encoding, then try to convert both `bdata[r,'COL1']` and `"Silloin tällöin"` to the resulting encoding with the `iconv()` and do the comparing again.